# JSON Login Authentification Zend Framework

Tags: php, json, extjs, zend-framework, authentication

I am creating a form login with ExtJS, and sending JSON data to do authentification within Zend Framework. The problem is, no matter what username and password I fill, login always succeed. Here's the related code :

Submit Function for Ext JS Form, where we send JSON data contained username and password.

```
var doLogin = function () {
    if (formPanel.getForm().isValid()) {
        formPanel.getForm().submit({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/zend/public/auth/valid',
            waitMsg: 'Processing Request',
            success: function (form, action) {
                document.location = '/zend/public/guestbook';
            },
            failure: function (form, action) {
                if (action.failureType = 'server') {
                    obj = Ext.util.JSON.decode(action.response.responseText);
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Login Failed', obj.errors.reason);
                } else {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Warning!', 'Authentification server is uneachable : ' + action.response.responseText);
                }
                formPanel.getForm().reset
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The Controller, we have ValidAction function to receive and send JSON data, and process to do the authentification.

```
public function validAction()
{
    if(!isset($this->session->isLogin)){
        $username = mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);

        $formdata = array('username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password); 
        if ($this->_process($formdata)) {
            $this->session->setExpirationSeconds(3600);
            $msg = '{success:true, result:{message:\'Welcome, '.$username.'!\'}}';
        } else {
            $msg = '{success:false, errors:{reason:\'Login failed, try again.\'}}';
        }
    }

protected function _process($values) {
    // Get our authentication adapter and check credentials
    $adapter = $this->_getAuthAdapter();
    $adapter->setIdentity($values['username']);
    $adapter->setCredential($values['password']);

    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);
    if ($result->isValid()) {
        $user = $adapter->getResultRowObject();
        $auth->getStorage()->write($user);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem lies in validAction, and weirdly I do var_dump to $this->process($formdata) and returns false, yet it always go to if function, message Success. Any ideas? Appreciated fellas.

**UPDATE :**

The var_dump :

```
Uncaught Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: 
array(2) {
   ["username"]=>
   string(2) "ad"
   ["password"]=>
   string(4) "pass"
}
bool(false)
string(59) "{success:false, errors:{reason:'Login failed, try again.'}}"
```

Comment: what version of php are you using? I'm just curious to know if your system supports the `mysql_` function.

Comment: Yes, it is php 5. I var dumped $username and $password variable too and succeed... Is this somehow related with the problem?

Comment: hard to say. I was under the impression that your system didn't support `mysql_*` functions. run error reporting and more var_dumps to see what does go through or not and compared to inputted values.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Now I recheck, it is indeed go to else path, so now the problem lies within JSON, I think? Maybe there is a structure mistake in it. Check my updates, please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Backend problem

You are outputting invalid JSON.

PHP provides json_encode to save you having to manually create json:

```
$response=array();
$response['success']=false;
$response['result']=array();
$response['message']='Welcome '.$username;
$msg = json_encode($response);
```

If you really don't want to use this you should add double quotes to your keys, and change to double quotes for your string properties too:

```
$msg = '{"success":true, "result":{"message":"Welcome, '.$username.'!"}}';
```

## Front end problem

You are using success and failure methods, but I can't see anything in your back end code to send status headers.

The failure method will only get called when a response returns with a non 200 status code. So you may need to either add this to your back end code, and/or also decode the response inside your success method to make sure that you have sent success:true as part of your json before redirecting.

To send the header in PHP 5.4 or newer:

```
http_response_code(401);
```

in 5.3 or older you have to use `header` method instead - but if you are running this version you should upgrade immediately so I wont include an example.

Comment: Thank you for the response code, so I put it in else condition, the var $msg should be passed to view index right? When passed, it should be triggered Ext alert that login failed, but mine's not working as it is supposed to be. Do you have any ideas?
P.S. passed msg variable when using wrong username and password is success false